# Hamiltonian and Lagrangian in Condensed Matter

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, condensed-matter, hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral

Can metal can be described as sum of many particle Lagrangian rather than Hamiltonian?

Comment: Writing the electronic Hamiltonian as a sum of one-particle Hamiltonians is an approximation. Within the same approximation, of course, the corresponding Lagrangian is a sum of one-body Lagrangians.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. However many widely used formalisms in statistical physics and quantum mechanics do use Hamiltonian formulation. E.g., Boltzmann distribution is usually written in terms of a Hamiltonian:
$$
\rho=Z^{-1}e^{-\beta H},
$$
but can be recast in terms of a path integral with a corresponding Lagrangian.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got that